# UndefinedError: list object has no element Undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js, flask, jinja2

I have this error when I run my app and I don't know what the problem is..

Here is my html code:

```
<select name="sel" onChange="myGraphFunction(this.value)">
{% for abs in absolute %}
<option value="{{abs.id|safe}}">{{abs.imp}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

where absolute is an array of dictionaries like

```
[{'id': 1, 'imp': someName, 'd': [{'key': someKey, 'y': someValue},{'key': .., 'y': ..},...]}, {'id': 2, 'imp': .., 'd': [{...}]}, ...]
```

Here is my javascript code where I get the value of the select so I can load some data:

```
function myGraphFunction(dd){
var testdata = {{absolute[dd].d|safe}}

nv.addGraph(function() {

var width = 500,
    height = 500;

var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
    .x(function(d) { return d.key })
    //.labelThreshold(.08)
    //.showLabels(false)
    .color(d3.scale.category10().range())
    .width(width)
    .height(height)
    .donut(true)
.labelType("percent");

chart.pie
    .startAngle(function(d) { return d.startAngle -Math.PI/2 })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return d.endAngle -Math.PI/2 });

  //chart.pie.donutLabelsOutside(true).donut(true);

  d3.select("#test2")
      //.datum(historicalBarChart)
      .datum(testdata)
    .transition().duration(1200)
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height)
      .call(chart);
nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
return chart;
});
```

The problem comes when I try to load absolute[dd].d in testdata.

I tried this instead:

```
if(typeof dd === 'undefined'){
var testdata = {{absolute[0].d|safe}}
}else{
var testdata = {{absolute[dd].d|safe}}
}
```

but I'm getting the same error...

Comment: are you sure you are not trying to access a index bigger than your array length ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dd` is a Javascript name, but it is *not set when rendering your template*. `dd` is then the Jinja2 `Undefined` object and your rendering fails.

You'd set the `testdata` list outside of your function, then refer to it inside the function:

```
var absolute = {{absolute|tojson|safe}}
function myGraphFunction(dd){
    var testdata = absolute[dd].d
```

I used the `tojson` filter to ensure that `absolute` is properly turned into a valid JavaScript literal.